# Methods for multiple search bars in a view

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

In a view I have 2 search bars that both need to use a separate searchBarTextDidBeginEditing method. However whenever I try to create a seperate method is shows as duplicate. With one method both are calling upon it.

I'm pretty sure i'm heading the methods wrong.

searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:nearSearch
searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:whatSearch

nearSearch and whatSearch are two different search bars.

I tried nearSearch: searchBarTextDidBeginEditing but am not sure if that is correct either.

Comment: Add tag for each searchBar and when is called searchbar didbeginediting check searchBar.tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate methods return a reference to the search bar object that calls it, a reason for that is precisely the issue you are describing, basically you should have a reference to your search bars, and compare to know which searchbar is calling the method and act accordingly..

say you have defined

```
UISearchBar *searchBarOne
UISearchBar *searchBarTwo
```

then in your delegate methods for example

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
      if(searchBar==searchBarOne)
      {
          //handle search bar one 
      }
      else if(searchBar==searchBarTwo)
      {
      //handle search bar two
      }
    }
```

Another solution is to set different tags for your search bars and compare the tags, as the comment to your question states.

hope that helps

Daniel

Comment: The first method worked perfectly, it split up the actions exactly how I wanted. Thanks!